# How Can i display a Modal onSubmit Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have a `<Form>` ( reduxForm ) Where user submits the values , as soon as the values got submitted It goes to another component `showResults` and that component Returns the `Modal` Component , Currently Modal Component is displays on the top of the App component ,

> How Can I get the Modal component Popup once user have
>   submitted(pressed the submit button) the values and then using those
>   values Modal gets displayed accordingly

`Form.jsx`

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {allQuestions}
  <div>
    <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
      Submit
    </button> // Once your press this button Modal should PopuP
    <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
      Clear Values
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

`showResults.jsx`

```
          <Form
                formData={formData}
                onSubmit={e => {
                    this.onSubmit(e);
                }}
            />
```

`Modal.jsx`

```
class ShowModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
return(
        <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal}>
          <h4>Total : {this.props.total} Out of 10</h4>
        </Modal>
      </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either store the model open state outside of the component and use a property (proper way) or ref (the anti pattern way):

```
<ShowModal ref={(modal) => this.modal = modal} />
```

and later:

```
this.modal.setState(show:true)
```

but the proper property way would be:

```
<ShowModal open={this.sate.showModal} />
```

probably since you are using redux you want to store your modal open/close state in redux state as well

Comment: And how can I store my modal state inside redux state ?

Comment: Add it to your redux store.